# when is the $n$-th cyclotomic polynomial irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials, cyclotomic-polynomials

It is well known that the cyclotomic polynomials
$\Phi_n(x)$
are irreducible over the field of rationals $\mathbb{Q}$.
I am curious about their reducibility over the real numbers $\mathbb R$.

We have $$\Phi_n(x)=\prod_{\substack{1\leqslant k\leqslant n \\\gcd(k,n)=1}}(x-\zeta_n^k)$$
where $\zeta_n:=e^{2\pi i/n}$.

<strike>So $\Phi_n$ is reducible when $2 k/n\in\mathbb Z$ for all $\gcd(k,n)=1$ which is clearly impossible.</strike>

So am I safe to conclude that $\Phi_n(x)$ are irreducible also over $\mathbb R$?

**EDIT**

As is mentioned by @Wojowu, every polynomial of degree $\geqslant 3$ is reducible in $\mathbb R$, so my question becomes... How to write down the irreducible factors of the cyclotomic polynomials over $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Every polynomial of degree greater than $2$ is reducible over $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Wojowu, Thanks for the comment...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $n \neq 1,2,3,4,6$ then $\phi(n) >2$ and
$$Q(x)=(x-\zeta_n)(x-\zeta_n^{n-1})$$
is a divisor of your polynomial with real coefficients.

**As for the edited question** For each $\gcd(k,n)=1$ the polynomial
$$Q(x ) = ( x-\zeta_n^k) (x-\zeta_n^{n-k}) $$
is irreducible over $\mathbb R$.

**Extra** Here is the proof that, for $n \neq 1,2$, and all $(k,n)=1, Q(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb R$.

First, it is easy to see that $\zeta_n^{n-k}=\overline{\zeta_n^{k}}$. You can see this either using the polar/trig form or by observing that
$$\zeta_n^{n-k}=\frac{\zeta_n^{n}}{\zeta_n^{k}}=\frac{1}{\zeta_n^{k}}=\frac{\overline{\zeta_n^{k}}}{\zeta_n^{k}\cdot \overline{\zeta_n^{k}}}=\overline{\zeta_n^{k}}$$

From here it follows immediately that the coefficients are real.

If $Q(x)$ were reducible, it would be a product of 2 linear terms, and hence its roots would be real. Therefore
$$\zeta_n^{k} \in \mathbb R$$

But then $\zeta_n^{k}$ would be a real root to $x^n-1$, and hence $\zeta_n^{k}  \in \pm 1$.

Since $(k,n)=1$ this is also a primitive $n$th root of unity, and hence $n \in \{1,2\}$, meaning the cyclotmic polynomial is linear.

Comment: Excellent answer. Any hint on how to prove that $Q(x)$ are irreducible?

Comment: Check that the coefficients of each $Q(x)$ are real, but the roots are not.

Comment: @qinr See the edit.

Comment: @N.S. Thanks a lot!

Comment: A very good answer. :)